# How to make function foo generate all the points?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
point = (3,6,9) # let all the elements of the tuple be none negative integers


def foo(point):
    for i in range(point[0]+1):
        for j in range(point[1]+1):
            for k in range(point[2]+1):
                yield (i,j,k)
```

My question is:
  What if I don't know the length of the tuple in advance?
  How to make function `foo` take any tuple as argument and do the same thing? e.g. what if `point = (3,6,9,0,7)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead:

```
from itertools import product

def foo(point):
    for combo in product(*(range(i + 1) for i in point)):
        yield combo
```